# How to replace, merge, or upsert new edges in Tinkerpop

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server, tinkergraph

When I try to add an edge that currently exists, for example:

```
g.addE('person-ip').from(g.V('customer:testID')).to(g.V('tel:5555555555')).property(id, 'testEdgeId').next()
```

I get an error like this

```
{"message":"Edge with id already exists: testEdgeId","Exception-Class":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","exceptions":["java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"],"stackTrace":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Edge with id already exists: testEdgeId\n\tat org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph$Exceptions.edgeWithIdAlreadyExists(Graph.java:1141)
```

Is there any setting I can use when setting up gremlin server or the tinkergraph properties that would allow duplicate edges to be merged, upserted, or ignored?

Answer (score 4):

There are no such settings in Gremlin Server or TinkerGraph - The pattern for upsert is as follows and is described in more detail on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447622/1831717):

```
g.E('testEdgeId').
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           V('customer:testID').as('start').
           V('tel:5555555555').
           addE('person-ip').
             from('start')
           property(id,'testEdgeId'))
```

**UPDATE:** As of TinkerPop 3.6.0, the `fold()/coalesce()/unfold()` pattern has been largely [replaced by the new steps](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_mergev_and_mergee) of `mergeV()` and `mergeE()` which greatly simplify the Gremlin required to do an upsert-like operation.