# Add edge if not exist using gremlin In Python

Tags: python, gremlin, amazon-neptune

right now I am trying to use python to implement some gremlin logic for neptunedb of aws. I want to check if one edge exist or not, if exist, ignore, otherwise add the edge.

for gremlin console, we can do it like this:

```
g.V().has('people','name', 'somebody').as('v').V().has('software','name','ripple').coalesce(__.inE('Created').where(outV().as('v')), addE('created').from('v').property('weight',0.5))
```

but I kind of lost how to convert this to python. It seems python cannot recoginize as('v')?
any hints? or where can i find reference documentation for gremlin python.

Comment: I refered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447308/add-edge-if-not-exist-using-gremlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [TinkerPop Gremlin documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#as-step):

> The term `as` is a reserved word in Python, and therefore must be referred to in Gremlin with `as_()`.

It's the same case for `from`. Just replace your `as` with `as_` and `from` with `from_` and it should work.

Comment: In addition, ```g.V().has('people','name', 'somebody')``` should changed to ```g.V().hasLabel(people).has('name', 'somebody')```, right?

Comment: One this, if I wanna to use id, should I do it using T? like ```g.V().hasLabel(people).has(T.id, 'somebody')```

Comment: For your first comment, that isn't necessary - has() will accept a label as the first argument: "has(label, key, value): Remove the traverser if its element does not have the specified label and provided key/value property.". I think you may want `hasIds()` for checking id, take a closer look at the docs for has() http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#has-step

Comment: 1. Are these two queries same thing? If so, do they have any difference in performance? 2. Actually I want to ask how to check a vertex exist, if I dump the vertices through csv with header ```"~id, ~label"```. Can I check it like ```g.V().has('people', id, 'somebody')``` or ```g.V().has('people',T.id, 'somebody')``` or ```g.V().has('people','id', 'somebody')```? Actually, I am a little confused about id in neptunedb

Answer (score 2):

Just to say this a bit more clearly, for python you need to do the following:

```
g.V().has('people','name', 'somebody').\
    as_('v').V().has('software','name','ripple').coalesce(
    __.inE('Created').where(__.outV().as_('v')), 
    __.addE('created').from_('v').\
    property('weight',0.5)).iterate()
```

The final `iterate()` at the end is important as you need to provide a terminal step when working in python, compared with the gremlin console. You can also use other terminal steps like `next()`, but without any terminal step the edge won't be created (at least in Neptune)