# Merge vertexes and edge between them at the same time in Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin

I have a source of data which I read and try to load it into my CosmosDB Graph. Each row that I fetch contains an information about multiple entities (person, software). What I am trying to do here is to:

- verify if such a vertex(es) already exist and generate a separate entity for missing entries (person, software)
- verify if an edge already exists (between this person and this software)
- create an edge between them

I've been making a reference to the following topics:
[CosmosDB Graph : “upsert” query pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758417/cosmosdb-graph-upsert-query-pattern), [Add edge if not exist using gremlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447308/add-edge-if-not-exist-using-gremlin/52447622#52447622) trying to combine them somehow but without much of a success.

I have tried the following:

```
g.V().has('person','name','vadas').
  fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('person').property('name','vadas')).as('v').
  V().has('software', 'name','ripple').
  fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('software').property('name','ripple')).
  coalesce(__.inE('created').where(outV().as('v')), addE('created').from('v'))
```

but it only creates the vertices without the edge between them.

I am also wondering if there's a bit more common approach to kind of:

```
1. Upsert entity A and keep a reference to it
2. Upsert entity B and keep a reference to it
3. Upsert entity C and keep a reference to it
....
1. Upsert edge between A and B
2. Upsert edge between A and C
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a reducing barrier step (i.e. `fold()`) that comes between you step label of "v" and where you try to retrieve it in `where()`. Note what happens more explicitly in the example below:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','vadas').
......1>   fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('person').property('name','vadas')).as('v').
......2>   V().has('software', 'name','ripple').
......3>   fold()
==>[v[5]]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','vadas').
......1>   fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('person').property('name','vadas')).as('v').
......2>   V().has('software', 'name','ripple').
......3>   fold().select('v')
gremlin>
```

As you can see, you can't `select('v')`. The path history for that traverser is gone. The [history is lost](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-barrier-steps) because you've reduced the stream from many traversers to one so "v" loses context in that merge.

When this sort of thing happens you typically just need to re-write your traversal a bit. I might do something like this in your case as it incurs the least change and maintains readability nicely:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','vadas').
......1>   fold().
......2>   coalesce(unfold(), addV('person').property('name','vadas')).
......3>   V().has('software', 'name','ripple').
......4>   fold().
......5>   coalesce(unfold(), addV('software').property('name','ripple')).
......6>   coalesce(__.inE('created').where(outV().has('person','name','vadas')), 
......7>            addE('created').from(V().has('person','name','vadas')))
==>e[24][2-created->5]
```

**UPDATE:** As of TinkerPop 3.6.0, the `fold()/coalesce()/unfold()` pattern has been largely [replaced by the new steps](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_mergev_and_mergee) of `mergeV()` and `mergeE()` which greatly simplify the Gremlin required to do an upsert-like operation. Under 3.6.0 and newer versions, you would write:

```
gremlin> g.mergeV([(label): 'person', name: 'vadas']).as('vadas').
......1>   mergeV([(label): 'software', name: 'ripple']).as('ripple').
......2>   mergeE([(from):outV, (to): inV, label: 'created']).
......3>     option(outV, select('vadas')).
......4>     option(inV, select('ripple'))
==>e[0][2-edge->5]
```

It's even nicer if you can use vertex identifiers thereby limiting the search criteria for `mergeV()` strictly to the `T.id` and avoiding late binding of vertices for `mergeE()`:

```
gremlin> g.mergeV([(id): 2]).
......1>     option(onCreate, [(label): 'person', name: 'vadas']).as('vadas').
......2>   mergeV([(id): 5]).
......3>     option(onCreate, [(label): 'software', name: 'ripple']).as('ripple').
......4>   mergeE([(from): 2, (to): 5, label: 'created'])
==>e[0][2-edge->5]
```

Comment: Appreciate it and beneficial example. Thanks a lot. I suspect in order to upsert the unique edge between them we can use with side effect ( 'drop') or something